# AudioSource not playing in Unity3d when EventSystem is in Scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

It took me a while to find it, I even had to re-create the scene and I happened to forget the EventSystem but... I am developing a simple 2D app. Push a button and it plays a random sound. This works, super easy. There's a Button UI element and the OnClick calls my script (which is on an object) and that script plays the audio.

I wanted to add a Pitch slider so the script assigns the audio clip to the AudioSource and I attached the UI Slider's OnValueChanged to my script. Now I realized I need to add my EventSystem but now my buttons won't play the Audio!

I have Debug.Log statements right before the Play() call so I know the button callback is working there's just no audio. Once I delete the EventSystem, the buttons play the audio just fine but now I can't use my slider. Ideas?

Using 2018.2 - Android Build

**EDIT**

```
private AudioSource audioSource;

....

IEnumerator PlayClip() {
    // Do stuff

    audioSource.clip = audioClip;
    audioSource.Play();
    while(audioSource.isPlaying)
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
}

public void ButtonPushed() {
    StartCoroutine(PlayClip());
}

public void ChangePitch(float pitch) {
    audioSource.pitch = pitch
}
```

Then the Slider `OnValueChanged()` just calls `ChangePitch` with a range -3 to 3.  All the code above is just one script and attached to one Controller object.

Don't worry, the Coroutine logic is a little better than that :)

Comment: I think we will need to see the code related to the slider's `OnValueChanged()` event to figure this one out.

Comment: Yeah, I figured someone would ask for code. Unfortunately can't get to it for a few hours.  I'll try my best, see edit above.

Comment: You said this is happening on Android...Is it also happening in the Editor?

Comment: Yes, it's happening on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue could be related to this [Unity issue](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/audiosource-audio-with-negative-pitch-doesnt-play-when-loop-is-disabled):

> [AUDIOSOURCE] AUDIO WITH NEGATIVE PITCH DOESN'T PLAY WHEN LOOP IS DISABLED
>
> User shouldn't use negative pitch value, unless one wants the clip to
> play backwards in the loop. If user wants it to play once through
> backwards, firstly he/she needs to set the position with
> AudioSource.time to the end of the clip and then play it.

I ran a test myself and I was able to reproduce your issue under the following conditions:

- Looping is disabled on the audio source.
- The pitch starts at a negative value.

If the starting value of the pitch is positive, or if it is negative with looping enabled, then I can use the slider to move the pitch between -3 and 3 without a problem.

Comment: That's interesting.  I picked those values only because that's what the AudioSource pitch range was when I added a default.  How would you change the pitch range?

Comment: Is your intent to play the clip in reverse at any point? If not, you could try calling `ChangePitch` with a range of 0 to 3 instead. You should be able to set the minimum value of your slider to 0 and the max to 3. Then pass that value directly to the `audioSource.pitch`.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably what I can do.  I do not plan on playing it backwards.  But that still doesn't explain the EventSystem.  When the EventSystem is removed the Audio plays.  The AudioSource.pitch range is still the same (-3, 3).

Comment: You said you were not able to use your slider without the event system, so I'm assuming that without the event system the `OnChangeValue()` is not firing, and thus `ChangePitch()` is never called.

Comment: Yeah, but a Sliders `OnChangeValue()` callback is only called when the user slides/interacts with the slider.

Comment: True. So it shouldn't have passed a negative value to begin with is what you're saying, right?  I have never messed around with pitch before so I am only theorizing off of what I have read.  When I get a chance tonight I will create a test scene and see what I can find if someone else has not found an answer by then.

Comment: I did some testing and I found that you can make the pitch positive or negative with a slider without any problems, as long as the starting pitch value in the audio source component is positive. If the starting pitch is negative in the audio source then the "loop" checkbox must be checked in order to hear anything. This aligns with the defect I mentioned above, however I'm not sure if it's related to your issue now as I have a feeling you aren't starting with a negative value. It's worth checking though.